# Python, validacion de numeros de telefonos con base Enacom

Tags: python, pandas, validación

Buenos días / tardes / noches a todos!
Tengo el siguiente problema, tengo una base con 10 columnas de telefonos, Telefono1, Telefono2....Telefono10, y quiero validar estos numeros, ya que me llegan con codigos de area errónes ya sea por ejemplo, +54549, +549, +54, 9, 00 en su mayoria. Esta validación la puedo hacer sin problemas, el tema es que cuando ejecuto mi código, a partir de la columna Telefono2 en adelante, me agrega un 0 al final de todos los numeros telefonicos de la base.

Tengo la siguiente base, les paso 2 filas unicamente para que sea mas claro:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Les comparto mi código:

```
import pandas as pd
import re


# Función para limpiar caracteres no numéricos y prefijos de un número de teléfono
def limpiar_telefono(numero):
    numero = re.sub(r"\D", "", str(numero))  # Elimina todos los caracteres no numéricos

    # Elimina los prefijos específicos del número de teléfono
    prefijos = ["54549", "549", "54", "9"]
    for prefijo in prefijos:
        if numero.startswith(prefijo):
            numero = numero[len(prefijo) :]
            break

    return numero


archivo = "Base.xlsx"
hoja = "Hoja1"
columnas_telefonos = [
    "Telefono1",
    "Telefono2",
    "Telefono3",
    "Telefono4",
    "Telefono5",
    "Telefono6",
    "Telefono7",
    "Telefono8",
    "Telefono9",
    "Telefono10",
]

df = pd.read_excel(archivo, sheet_name=hoja)

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    numeros_telefono_unicos = []
    for columna_telefono in columnas_telefonos:
        numero_actual = row[columna_telefono]
        if pd.notnull(numero_actual):
            numero_actual = limpiar_telefono(numero_actual)
            if numero_actual and numero_actual not in numeros_telefono_unicos:
                numeros_telefono_unicos.append(numero_actual)

    for i, columna_telefono in enumerate(columnas_telefonos):
        if i < len(numeros_telefono_unicos):
            numero_telefono = numeros_telefono_unicos[i]
            if numero_telefono.endswith("0"):
                row[columna_telefono] = (
                    numero_telefono[:-1] + "0"
                )  # Mantener el "0" al final si termina en "0"
            else:
                row[columna_telefono] = numero_telefono
        else:
            row[columna_telefono] = None  # Asignamos None en lugar de un espacio vacío

    df.loc[index] = row

nuevo_archivo = "Nueva_Base.xlsx"
df.to_excel(nuevo_archivo, index=False)
```

Una vez que se ejecuta el código, me devuelve lo siguiente:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ordena los telefonos hacia los espacios en blanco por manteniendo el orden original de los mismos, pero a partir de la columna Telefono2, me agrega un 0 al final de cada numero que no deberia estar y no logro dar con la solucion.

Espero me puedan ayuda.

Gracias de antemano.

Saludos!

Comment: podrias colocar, por lo menos 3 ejemplos de entrada y cual seria el resultado esperado? porque por tu explicacion no logre comprenderte del todo